# Create dynamic button names in Jquery UI Dialog based on the trigger anchor's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done a jquery UI dialog box and it works but I need to pass the value of the a tag (the name) into the jquery for for the buttons but been looking and trying many different things and nothing :(

What I got:

a tag (Value filled by PHP):

```
<a href="#" class="name">'.$name.'</a>
```

Html div:

```
<div id="name" title="view or send this user a message?"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#name" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 500,
      show: {
        effect: "fold",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 500
      },
      buttons: {
                    //Names need to go here as part of the buttons
        "Send " + $(this).data('name') + " a message": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "view " + $(this).data('name') + "profile ": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

    $( "a.name" ).click(function() {
    //Pass name to form
    $("#name").data('name', $("a#name").text());
    $( "#name" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

});

so I need to get the name from the a#name and i tried .text(). To the jquery for to use for the buttons.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite some issues in the dialog creation, Try this way.

You are concatenating in the object property while creating the buttons, which is invalid syntax, plus trying to access `data('name')` when it doesn't exists during initialization yet. Instead create the buttons when it is required i.e before the dialog show when you click on the hyperlink that is where you know what is the `name` that needs to be appended to the buttons.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K7S4B/)

```
 $(function () { // Same as document ready. only one of them is needed. No need to chain them

    var dial = $("#name").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        show: {
            effect: "fold",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 500
        }
    });

   $("a.name").click(function () {
     //Pass name to form
     var name = $(this).text();
     dial.dialog({
        buttons: getButtons(name),
        autoOpen:true
     })
   });
});

function getButtons(name) {
    var dialog_buttons = {}; //Create the buttons here.
    dialog_buttons["Send " + name + " a message"] = buttonCallBack; //set the call back.
    dialog_buttons["view " + name + " profile"] = buttonCallBack; // assign different call back if required
    return dialog_buttons;

}

function buttonCallBack() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for the `a` tag is wrong.  Change

```
$("#name").data('name', $("a#name").text());
```

to

```
$("#name").data('name', $('a.name').text());
```

Comment: Did not work, it worked before, its just I can't pass data to the form